# Android : How to change img src and margin top at a button onclick (xml)

Tags: android, xml, button, margin

when I click a button I want to change his image and at the same time I want to change its margin top when the button is pressed. How can I achieve that :/ (xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/letsgoog"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/letsgob" />
</selector>
```

what do i need to add to change the margin :)?

Comment: you can make your own custom button and declare which states should have which backgrounds. just search for 'custom button' or something. Dunno about the margin.

Comment: this code does this already :) (image) letsgob is going change to (image) letsgoog, when pressed :)

Comment: Well you need to change the margin in the code, that's for sure. Just search how to change position of a button or something then.

Answer (score 0):

have you delcared both images in your Manifest?

and sometime having the image twice in the "image folder" (example: if you have cat.jp x2 it will cause a fatal error and close). so double check that.

also put "" into the same column as "

hope i help